# Filtering only dirs and xml file in QFileSystemModel in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

i have implemented a custom file browing dialog with the help of

```
QListView
QTreeView
QFileSystemModel
```

### What i want !

a browsing dialog which use to browse xml file only. So i want to show dirs and xml files only in QListView

#### if a dir has xml file then xml file will list under that dir

#### otherwise just display dir as empty ( no matter how many it holds except xml )

like in most of cases where you are browsing a specific type of file. as in MSWord ( show only .doc and .docx to browse)

### What i have done

```
m_ptrModelForTree  = new QFileSystemModel(this);
m_ptrModelForTree->setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
m_ptrModelForTree->setRootPath("");
ui->treeView->setModel(m_ptrModelForTree);
ui->treeView->hideColumn(1);
ui->treeView->hideColumn(2);
ui->treeView->hideColumn(3);
ui->treeView->header()->hide();

m_ptrModelForList = new QFileSystemModel(this);
m_ptrModelForList->setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
m_ptrModelForList->setRootPath("");
ui->listView->setModel(m_ptrModelForList);
ui->listView->setRootIndex(m_ptrModelForList->index("c:\\"));
```

### What i got

dialog which showing all dirs and all file ( but i need only xml file to display )

### What i tried

```
m_ptrModelForList->setNameFilters(QStringList()<<".xml");
```

but it showing xml file only, not dirs.

please give me suggestion what to do.

Comment: Did you try `m_ptrModelForList->setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);` (`QDir::AllDirs` instead of `QDir::Dirs`)? According to the docs, this should list all directories and not apply the name filter to them

Comment: @Andreas yea, same result showing all dirs and files

Comment: I think that Andreas suggested you the right way. Combine changning the flag to `QDir::AllDirs` and `setNameFilters` and you should get the result.

Comment: this is what i make change    m_ptrModelForList->setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    m_ptrModelForList->setNameFilters(QStringList()<<".xml");
    m_ptrModelForList->setNameFilterDisables(false);       Now showing only dirs

Comment: Can you provide a small, complete, runnable example so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @andres thanks for solution. it was my mistake that i was providing name filter as ".xml" not as "*.xml"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's a solution suggested by @Andreas in comments to the question. 
My contribution is pointing to another mistake in the name filter.

**Solution**: **how to show all dirs + files filtered by extension**

1. Use flag QDir::AllDirs. According to [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#Filter-enum) this flag is intented to avoid applying the filter to folders.

   > setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
2. Use `setNameFilters` to set a filter for files. The filters are [wildcards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character#File_and_directory_patterns).
   Your mistake that use set it to ".xml" which means that a file shouldn't have its name but extension only to match your filter. The right filter is:

   > setNameFilters(QStringList() << "*.xml")