# Hide filtered files with QFileSystemModel, setNameFilterDisables(false) hides everything

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create simple file filter for my viewer.
Idea is to show only files allowed by filter and hide others (not disable them).
Some useful answers were found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927069/filtering-only-dirs-and-xml-file-in-qfilesystemmodel-in-qt) and [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25933-limit-QDirModel-file-type), and using those examples I wrote this simple code:

```
QDir dir("c:/Projects/Qt/Data/spiro/");

QFileSystemModel* model = new QFileSystemModel;
model->setRootPath(dir.path());
model->setReadOnly(true);
model->setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);

model->setNameFilters(QStringList() << "*.dbx");
// without this line, all files are displayed, filtered out are disabled
model->setNameFilterDisables(false);

m_treeView->setModel(model);
```

However, it is not working as expected.
When using line with `setNameFilterDisables(false)`, I get no files at all.
This is not expected behavior for me as I would expect that files that do not pass the filter,
are not going to be shown at all.
This is described in the documentation:

> This property holds whether files that don't pass the name filter are
>   hidden or disabled.

So, how to properly filter the files and display only filtered ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to tree set root index:

```
m_treeView->setRootIndex(model->index(dir.path()));
```

If you want to keep directories visible, along with the filtered files, use `QDir::AllDirs` flag intead of `QDir::Dirs`.